# text in button disappears on click

Tags: css, button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOzEI.png)So im styling a sign in button (__signin) it is inside a container (btnContainer) along with a forgot password button (__forgotpass).

What's happening is the sign in text is disappearing while the button is clicked...so if i hold the button down to stay in the active state the text is gone when i release the button it re-appears.

Ive tried looking this up cant really find much...the only thing i can think of is to separate the sign in text from the button because right now the text is marked up inside the button element. So what would be the best way to do this? just put the sign in inside a span and position absolute? But a part of me thinks there is a way to keep the html markup like it is but i just don't know.

i would like to do this without javascript if possible.. heres some html and css of the button

HTML

```
<div class="btnContainer">
    <button type="submit" class="btnContainer__signin">Sign In</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btnContainer__forgotpass">Forgot Password?</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .btnContainer { //This is the container for the sign-in button and forgot password button
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   height: 5rem;
   max-width: 10rem;
   margin-top: auto;

    &__signin {
        color: var(--color-text-primary);
        background: var(--color-btn-background);
        border: .50rem solid var(--color-btn-background);
        border-radius: 2.5rem;
        border-style: outset;
        z-index: 1000;
        cursor: pointer;
        min-width: 10rem;
        text-transform: none;
        transition: transform .5s ease;
        // transition: all .5s ease;
    }

    &__signin:active {
        transform: translateY(2px);
    }

    &__forgotpass {
        cursor: pointer;
        color: var(--color-text-primary);
        border-bottom: var(--line);
        margin-top: 1rem;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    &__forgotpass
    :hover,
    :active {
        color: var(--color-text-secondary);
    }
}

 --color-text-primary: #EFEFEF;
 --color-text-secondary: #3EB54A;

 --color-btn-background: #3EB54A;
 --color-btn-hover: #3EB54A;
```

Comment: Any chance the values of `--color-btn-background` and `--color-text-secondary` are the same?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to include variables.. --color-text-primary: #EFEFEF;
    --color-text-secondary: #3EB54A; --color-btn-background: #3EB54A; So yes they are but thats just for the forgot pass button. sorry if thats confusing i left the password styling in but ill take that out now

Comment: Actually, rollback that edit because I believe it contains information vital to your issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following selector is targeting both buttons when they are active.

```
&__forgotpass
:hover,
:active {
    color: var(--color-text-secondary);
}
```

Since `--color-btn-background` and `--color-text-secondary` are the same, it looks like the text of `btnContainer__signin` is missing. It's not missing, it's just the same color as the background.

Try changing the selector to only target the `btnContainer__forgotpass` button.

```
&__forgotpass:hover,
&__forgotpass:active {
    color: var(--color-text-secondary);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow yeah that worked! thats awesome thank you! so my markup was just incorrect in my scss? you have to target the element with the pseudo classes individually? So it was just inheritance because the active did not have a class assigned to it specifically so it applied to all items in the container?

Comment: Even more broadly, I believe your selector was targeting *any* element with the `active` pseudo class. Expanded from SCSS, the selector reads `btnContainer__forgotpass:hover, :active`.

Comment: well live and learn, thanks for the help.